# Laravel MySQL Select from nested JSON-column

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

I have JSON-column in MySQL database.

**Controller**

This is my sample code that gets the `selected_products` from the table and returns it as JSON which I intend to use for chart data.
What I am trying to do is get the `name` of the `product`.

```
$products = Order::select('selected_products')->get();

return response()->json(['test_data' => $products], 200);
```

The JSON response may view [here](https://api.myjson.com/bins/n3qhi)

If I do it like this:

```
$products = Order::select('selected_products->name')->get();
```

It returns an error of:

> *SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>'$."name"' from `orders`' at line 1 (SQL: select `selected_products`->'$."name"' from `orders`)*

I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you loop through `$products` array ?

```
$porductsNames = array();

$products = Order::select('selected_products')->get();

foreach ($products as $product){
   foreach($product('selected_products') as $p){
        $productsNames[] = $p['name'];
   }
}

// Then you can use it
dd($productsNames);
```

Comment: Your answer looks promising however, I tried it out and it returns `null`.

Comment: @Emjey23 can you share your Teamviewer details I can check it for you!

Comment: Thats great, downloading Teamviewer.

Comment: Don't post teamviewer details on a public site! Are you crazy?

Comment: Any private messaging system.

Comment: Thank you for the great help. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the $products as following line and check it work.

```
$products = Order::all('selected_products');
```

If it's not possible use the sql statement like below

```
$products=DB::select("SELECT selected_products from orders")
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I believe I haven't fully explained what I am trying to get. I do get the `selected_products`, but inside of it cannot such as `selected_products->name`. That is what I am trying to get. Thank you.

Comment: Is it ok now. Is my answer is usefull ?